# Is reliable using post type pods to store 200k pods with many fields?

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I would to know if it is reliable for a web portal to use post type pods for store 200k companies with many fields and with a couple of relationship fields multi-value.

I don’t know if it is better to use Advanced Content Type pods and to have a independent data tables from wp_post and wp_postmeta.

However I would to know if I lose many done things if I use Advanced Content Type at the time to add, remove, delete, find pods, manage relations, search into the pods, etc.

I see that Pods developers recommend to use Post Type Pods, but i am afraid with the table wp_postmeta, that stores all the fields of pods (one line one field) and that may easyly achieve 3KK of records or much more.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a Pods question, in regards to performance for Post Types / Custom Fields, that's a general WordPress thing.

However, we've put together some comparisons to help you see the differences between storing things in custom fields vs their own tables:

http://pods.io/docs/comparisons/compare-storage-types/

We also put together a comparison of what you get with Advanced Content Types vs Custom Post Types. So it's really up to you, you can build some extremely streamlined content types with Advanced Content Types, or you can build your content type in a highly compatible way that plays nicely with most themes / plugins out there that integrate and add features to Custom Post Types.

http://pods.io/docs/comparisons/compare-content-types/

Alternatively, you can choose to enable 'Table Storage' for your Custom Post Types selectively, so you can store your Pods-created custom fields in their own table and get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Thank you, that was my option, choose Custom Post Types to hold the compatibility and use table based storage for the performance. I think that if I use meta based storage I'll get a big table in wp_postmeta that impacts negatively in the performance.